# Getting "The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type Optional" Error in Java File

Tags: java, eclipse, is-empty

My Eclipse Java compiler doesn't recognize the *isEmpty* method in my code. I understand that *isEmpty* is from Java 1.6, but I'm using 1.8. I've also tried importing **org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils**, but that doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
@Repository("fakeDao") 
public class FakePersonDataAccessService implements PersonDao {
    
    private static List<Person> DB = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Override
    public int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person) {
        DB.add(new Person(id, person.getName()));
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> selectAllPeople() {
        return DB;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int deletePersonById(UUID id) {
        Optional<Person> personMaybe = selectPersonById(id);
        if (personMaybe.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        DB.remove(personMaybe.get());
        return 1;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Optional<Person> selectPersonById(UUID id) {
        return DB.parallelStream()
                .filter(person -> person.getId().equals(id))
                .findFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public int updatePersonById(UUID id, Person person) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `#isPresent`? `#isEmpty` is not a method in `java.util.Optional`, which was added as of Java 8.

Comment: @Rogue It is a method of Optional but only from Java 11 onwards

Comment: Thanks for the catch @greg-449, I need to seriously take the time to move on from java 8 at some point.

Comment: I think you should add some code to your post. Although @greg-449 has provided you solution.

Comment: I've having some trouble uploading the screenshots. I'll have to paste the code in.

Comment: @JoshZepeda I’m glad you chose to copy and paste the code instead of using a screenshot. See [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged) for why you made the right choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `isEmpty` method of `Optional` was not added until Java 11.

For Java 8 you will have to use `! isPresent()`